# Minify jQuery generated with JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, minify

I have web pages generated by JSP which sometimes also include jQuery code. Some of the AJAX calls within jQuery need parameters from JSP. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<%=ivy.html.startref("API/regions.ivp")%>",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.regions, function() {
            $("#regions").append(
                $("<option></option>").val(this.imPersonalNumber).html(this.cn + " [" + this.imJobTitleDescription + "]")
            )
        });

        $("#regions").val($("#tempRegions").val())
    }
})
```

Is there any way I can minify this kind of code?

Comment: I used http://www.minifyjs.com/javascript-compressor/ and it seems to work with the `<% %>`.
What's your problem exactly?

Comment: What kind of code? If you feel boring to write `url, dataType, success` options, you may give `$.get` or `$.post` a try.

Comment: sometimes.. I wish I can downvote comments.

Comment: @Adnan I tried the compressor you suggested, but when I replace the code with the compressed one, I get unexpected identifier errors :\ Other compressors wouldn't even compress, because it had `"<%=blablabla("string")%>"`. Maybe the unexpected idenfitier comes from somewhere else, but the code itself works without errors when uncompressed.

Comment: To by pass syntax checking by some compressors, replace `<%=blablabla("string")%>` with anything you want, `lasuhrgudrfg` for example. Now after the compression you can replace `lasuhrgudrfg` with `<%=blablabla("string")%>` back again.

Comment: @Adnan I'll try that, at least I would see if the error comes from JSP or from somewhere else. Is there any kind of coding style which would work uncompressed, but create problems when compressed to one line?

Comment: I haven't encountered any problems of that sort. Why not try a more mainstream and well tested compressor, like [YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)

Comment: @Adnan I tried YUI, getting syntax errors. Having a look at the lines with errors. Edit: Errors seem to occur where JSP content begins.

Comment: @Adnan I replaced the JSP contents with normal strings, compressed it and then put back the JSP again. Works now :) Might want to post your sugesstion as answer, so I can upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you replace the JSP content with some string of your choice, the use [YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) for example, and after the compression you can replace that string with the original JSP content.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you like to compress HTML page (containing jquery calls)  generated by JSP. Best solution would be to implement servlet filter compressing outgoing HTTP ( with something like this: http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/ )

Another popular solution is reverse proxy with Apache HTTPD  compressing outgoing HTML with gzip -  this will give you most saving of the traffic while maintaining source code readability.

Comment: `HTML Compressor` doesn't affect content inside the `<script>` tag so you'd have to use an external JS compressor

Comment: Unfortunately configuring the web server itself is not a option, since the webserver is integrated in a workflow tool. What I'm searching is a compressor where I just replace my code with a minfied version.

Comment: In this case best solution will be gzipping  content stream via servlet filter - but I'm not sure if this is already available